# Make .NET exes compatible with all windows users (xp to 7)

Tags: c#, compatibility

If I create an application in c# 3.5, how could I make the exe compatible with all windows users? 
I tried creating a couple of simple applications and send the exes from the bin folder and everyone has complained that they could not use them because they didn't have the update platform.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, C# 3.5 can generate code for .NET 2.0 or newer, by changing the project options.

But your users still will need the right version of .NET installed, and .NET 2.0 is not included in XP, not even with SP3.

If installing framework updates is too much to expect of your users, you will need to use native code instead of .NET.

Comment: Is there any chance of installing dependencies with a setup? Or is the right version of .NET Framework mandatory?

Comment: You could install a newer version of .NET via an optional Windows Update - is that an option?

Comment: @BrokenGlass, how could I do that?

Comment: @Hallaghan: You can bundle .NET Framework with your installer, but I wouldn't.  Your users who already have it installed will hate you for having a 200 MB setup program when then only needed 3 MB.  My recommendation: Have your setup program (or launcher, either way it must be a small native program) check for .NET framework and if it's not installed, open the Microsoft Download website.  That way your download stays small, and it's fairly easy for your users to fix their lack of .NET.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, I like your suggestion fairly much. It sounds like the correct choice to make seeing as though it won't be a burden to the end-user and it will make things clean. +1 for that and the right answer goes to you. Thanks to everyone else for helping too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the target platform to a previous .NET framework version:

Check `Menu| Project | Properties | Application` and the setting Target framework, set it i.e. to .NET 2.0 if required - you will not be able to use new features then though - a better alternative would be updating those machines to add .NET 4.

Comment: However, a clean install of XP SP3 still would be unable to run the result.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine as long as you have it set to Any CPU and the users have the same .NET framework version installed.

Comment: Actually, `x86` is often more compatible than `AnyCPU`.  You think he's got Itanium users?